# How to setup WebGL autocomplete on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, webgl, visual-studio-code

I need to develop a game HTML5 and WebGL on JS, but the editor does not suggest methods, fields, enums related to WebGL to become easier. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? What do their docs say? See [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to reformat the question so it is easier for folks to answer.

Comment: I've got a folder project, with HTML and JS files into it. It's only linked with the tag <script src="">... It works fine the commands in JS with WebGL but the editor does not autocomplete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should download WebGl.d.ts, for example [from here](https://github.com/RicoP/webgl.d.ts)

And reference this file in first string of your JS file:

```
/// <reference path="webgl.d.ts" />
```